# How do I reload the dom in jquery mobile app

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

Please I need somen to help me before I loose my mind.

I am developing a mobile app with jquery mobile 1.4. The problem is that when users edit a form content it saves in local storage but does not show unless I manually refresh the browser so I implemented the following script

```
       //After the selected employee has been edited
localStorage.setItem("employees", JSON.stringify(employees));   //set the update values to localstorage
alert('Eployee updated Successfully');
       $.mobile.changePage("#home_page");
```

To make the dom refresh so that I dont have to manually refresh I implemented this

```
 window.location.reload('#employee_list_view_page');

      return true;
```

Which works well but when I converted to android using phone gap, once it updates it brings a white screen and the app hangs (like crashing).

Please what other way can I refresh or reload the dom that is more effecient. Or is there a way I can set a timeout for the refresh to stop after some seconds so the blank screen stops.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/
Something like:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change","index.html",{reloadPage:true});
```

Unfortunately this is deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4, but the new method `reload` is affected by a bug.
Have a try and keep an eye on this: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7406

Comment: thanks but at the moment my method window.loacation.reload(); works well, the problem is that when I converted to android app using phonegap, when it reloads it freezes. Is there a way I can stop it (or set it to time out and stop the reload process)? Thanks